# I'm sometimes unable to get the current location even when the GPS is on but Wifi is off, why?

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I have an android app which uses google map and has a feature to show the current location. I have received few comments saying that "the current location is not coming up even if the GPS is on." I tried it with couple of devices but I could not see the issue but yesterday I faced the issue on my phone too where it was working fine earlier.

The solution that I figured out is if the current location is not coming up then turn off the wi-fi and use mobile internet for getting the current location and it started showing up. I know it seems little weird but it worked for me. Please suggest me the changes needed in my code, if I am missing something. I can't suggest the above workaround for my app users.

```
locMgr = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
boolean enabled = locMgr.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
cEnabled = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("cEnabled");

if (!enabled && !cEnabled) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alt_bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alt_bld.setMessage("Would you like to activate GPS?\n(recommended- Yes)")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                 dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

    AlertDialog alert = alt_bld.create();
    // Title for AlertDialog
    alert.setTitle("Activate GPS?");
    // Icon for AlertDialog
    alert.setIcon(R.drawable.location1);
    alert.show();       
}  

ImageButton clocButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.cLoc);
clocButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    getToMyLocation();
        return false;
    }
});

private void getToMyLocation() {
    mapView.invalidate();
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String provider = locMgr.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    Location lastLoc = locMgr.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    if(lastLoc != null) {
        GeoPoint lastPoint = new GeoPoint((int)(lastLoc.getLatitude()*1E6), (int)(lastLoc.getLongitude()*1E6));
        center = lastPoint;
        showLocation(lastPoint);
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Waiting for current location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    myLocOverlay.enableMyLocation();
    myLocOverlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            GeoPoint loc = myLocOverlay.getMyLocation();
            mapView.getController().setCenter(loc);
            center = loc;
        }
    });
}

private void showLocation(GeoPoint location) {
    if (location != null) {
        myLocOverlay.enableMyLocation();
        mapView.getController().animateTo(location);
    }
}
```

I have added following permissions in manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the Android Developers' [Making Your App Location-Aware](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/location/index.html) tutorial before and it has worked fine for me. Have you looked through this and compared it to your own code?

You may see something you are missing, or a better way of implementing parts of it, which may clear up these issues.

Comment: I am setting default criteria for location and looking for the best provider but it seems, String provider = locMgr.getBestProvider(criteria, false); returning a null provider. but why?